# SQL 2008 Managmnet Studio issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, blueprism

I am new to Blue Prism Version:5.0

I a have been using BP since few days suddenly when i am trying to login to the application both the UserName and Password fields were grayed with an

> Warning: Couldnt connect to database "Default Connection"

When I have opened the SQL management studio when trying to connect to database getting the error as:

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1).

Any suggestion will be helpful
Thanks in advance
With Regards
Harsha Vardhan

Comment: Have you checked that the service is running?

Comment: At a pure guess (as you've tagged it) SSMS doesn't connect to MySQL, only SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all

What was the problem I too don't know but with a restart everything was set and now I am able to connect to SQL.